# Download your own photos from Instagram via a web app

Tags: api, instagram

I've looked through the API documentation on Instagram and researched the web, but I haven't been able to find a consistent answer to whether it's possible to download your own Instagram photos via a web app.

For example, I'm trying to write a web app which allows users to authenticate into their Instagram account, and then download all their Instagram photos into the web app and display it.

The closest thing I've seen on Instagram is the following url: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media

But can someone confirm if this is the correct endpoint? Also, if this is the correct endpoint, assuming that I uploaded a high-resolution photo, would that photo be available for me to download in high resolution via the API?

Comment: Yes, it is all possible. You are on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - do you have any advice for the high-resolution photo piece?

Comment: why don't you use the api-console to make some test calls? http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/

Comment: thanks for the awesome suggestion - can't believe I missed that page!

Comment: Did you get on? The "standard" (which is the high-resolution) `URL` is packed with the others in a `JSON` string. You can do literally what you want with it. But watch the limit on requests per hour.

Comment: Yup, got it working - thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @wmock Try this web app https://saveaxe.now.sh/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easy with Google Chrome and you don't need the API:

I wrote a small ES6 script that does just this ( let's you view and save instagram images and videos on right click )

Here's the code:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', (event) => {
  const elements = document.elementsFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
  const mediaSource = elements.find(element => /img|video/gi.test(element.tagName)).getAttribute('src');
  mediaSource && window.open(mediaSource, '_blank');
});
```

What it does is when you click on image or video, it get's all elements under the mouse, finds the image/video and opens it in new tab. Then you save it.

Also, it's available as a [Chrome Extension](https://instasee.me)

Answer (score 0):

Download instagram images of a particular user or tag using python. Source is included both console and GUI. Install all the dependencies before running. Remember this code is not optimized for python 3. Make sure that the profile is public or else only the profile picture will be downloaded.
link to my github repo:https://github.com/techweed/instagami

Its a python2 script and you need to install it for this to work.
The images would be downloaded to your working directory.